# Some good reading on polygon algorithms

Tags: computational-geometry, reference-request

What are some good resources (books, articles, sites) about polygon intersection and union algorithms?

Comment: convex or non-convex polygons?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526352/how-to-intersect-two-polygons ?

Answer (score 4):

I am a big fan of Joseph O'Rourke's works.  I highly recommend his book Computational Geometry in C (2nd edition) because it has a particularly good balance of theory and implementation.  Chapter 7 contains direct information pertaining to polygon intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Paul's suggestion is great, I would just like to add two more:

"Geometric Tools for Computer Graphics", Schneider

"Computational Geometry" Mark deBerg et al.

On this note, my 2cents (coming from experience): if you are considering coding such algorithms, I advise you kindly to take a look at Boost::Geometry and/or CGAL libray first, there is no need (hopefully) to re-invent the wheel. If you are coding in C++, that is....

Answer (score 2):

[GPC, General Polygon Clipper](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/) is a good implementation for boolean operations on polygons based on [Vatti's clipping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm). The page also contains [links](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/#Links) to other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is to look for modern algorithms for related problems, like [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection), etc.  Often there are good strategies in slightly different application if you have a particular problem you're trying to solve.

As for implementation, you could check out the [Boost Polygon Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm).

A couple general books for Computational Geometry that are on my shelf are:

[Computational Geometry: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961313) by Franco Preparata and Michael Shamos is yet another good introductory book on computational geometry algorithms.

[Computational Geometry: An Introduction Through Randomized Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133363635) by Ketan Mulmuley  is an excellently constructed book good algorithmic coverage of a wide variety of algorithms for geometric problems; all done through randomized methods.

Answer (score 2):

This one is quite old and not well known, but it is a good one:

- [M. V. Leonov and A. G. Nikitin. An Efficient Algorithm for a Closed Set of Boolean Operations on Polygonal Regions in the Plane (draft English translation). A. P. Ershov Institute of Informatics Systems, Preprint 46, 1997](http://www.complex-a5.ru/polyboolean/downloads/polybool_eng.pdf)